# QRegExp not matching anything

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt5, qregexp

I've an application made by another person and I need to fix it. There's a chart on the view and a textbox for filtering the chart but filter doesnt work. For some reason QRegExp cant find anything.

I am using QT5.12.1 and VS2015.

```
void ChartWidget::filterSeriesByName(QString name) {
//  QString text=ui.lineEditFilterByName->text();
    QRegExp regExp(name, Qt::CaseSensitive);
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(regExp);
    setFilterLabel();

    foreach (QLegendMarker* marker, chart->legend()->markers())
    {
        if(regExp.isEmpty() || regExp.exactMatch(marker->series()->name())) {
            setMarkerVisible(marker,true,true);
        }
        else {
            setMarkerVisible(marker,true,false);
        }
    }
}

void ChartWidget::setFilterLabel() {
    //resetVerticalHeader();
    QString filteredCount = QString::number(proxyModel->rowCount()).append(" / ");
    filteredCount.append(QString::number(model->rowCount()));
    filteredCount.append(" kayıt gösteriliyor");

    ui.labelFilter->setText(filteredCount);

    QFont font = ui.labelFilter->font();
    if (proxyModel->rowCount() != model->rowCount()) {
        ui.labelFilter->setForegroundRole(QPalette::Link);
        font.setStyle(QFont::StyleItalic);
        ui.labelFilter->setFont(font);
    } else {
        ui.labelFilter->setForegroundRole(QPalette::WindowText);
        font.setStyle(QFont::StyleNormal);
        ui.labelFilter->setFont(font);
    }
}
```

Comment: What chars does `name` contains? If there are any special chars, like `(` or `[`, the regex may not work as expected.

Comment: Its a normal string typed into textbox. Like entering country names to filter chart. So in that way `name` would be "Brazil" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had somewhat similar thingy and it worked when I've added a regex to parameter QString. Try this:

```
....
QString filterStr = "^.*"+name+".*$";
QRegExp regExp(filterStr);
....
```